Condition to send an email returns false when it is a recurring series meeting but works perfectly when it si a one time meeting
I have a workflow that sends an email before a meeting, I Have used this workflow before with Meetings that occur just once. However, when I try to use it with meetings that occur every week I ran into the problem that the condition to send the message iCalUid is always met with a false statement, I already tried using Series MasterID but it also throws false everytime. I know the IDs are the correct ones because I retrieve them using a workflow and the ids work when the meeting is a one time meeting. What can I do so this works with recurring series meetings as well?
The following workflow :

And I also want to send it to the required attendees and using the subject of the email :


What is your flow doing before this? Update your question with a little more context. Like, is it getting all calendar events, looping through and checking if they are of a certain type?
